# Meaning of という手も

Tags: words

In an anime a character says this:

> この際だからちゃんと話すという手も

which is translated as "Well, in this case, telling her might be a good idea"; I tried looking on Jisho, Weblio and Weblio Thesaurus trying to understand that `という手も`, but I was unable to find anything. The character was cut off, so I think something should come after `も`, but I'm not sure that's the case and if so I can't understand what should follow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 「この際{さい}だからちゃんと話{はな}すという手も」

is a valid and natural-sounding "sentence" as-is in informal and/or spoken Japanese.  That it lacks a verb at the end should not surprise you if you are someone who has already been watching anime in the original Japanese.

The verb phrase that is left unsaid at the end would be 「ある」、「あると思{おも}う」、「あるんじゃない？」、「あるでしょう」, 「あるよね」, etc.

> 「[Verb Phrase] + という手もある」

means:

> "(Someone) has an option of [Verb Phrase]"

That option is to 「ちゃんと話す」 ("to tell the truth", "to speak honestly", etc.)

「手」, in this context, means "***means***", "***way***", etc.  I used "option" myself as I feel it fits better in the English translation.  Jisho does give you these meanings [here](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%89%8B).  See #6.

In Japanese, it is usually the shortest originally Japanese words as 「手」 that have multiple (and often highly unexpected) meanings.  It is generally ***not*** our loanwords, Sino or otherwise.

My own TL:

Literal: "**On this occasion, you have an option of telling the truth**."

Free: "**This should be a good opportunity to tell the truth**."